# Let f(z) be a non-constant analytic function on the region D = {z ∈ C||z| ≤ 1}. Suppose |f(z)| ≤ 1 for all z∈D.

Tags: cauchy-integral-formula

Let f(z) be a non-constant analytic function on the region D = {z ∈ C||z| ≤ 1}. Suppose |f(z)| ≤ 1 for all z∈D.

Show that if |w|<1, then
$\frac{|f′(w)|}{1-|f(w)|^2}$ ≤ $\frac{1}{1-|w|^2}$

Here is my working:

[image]

May I know where did I gone wrong?

Comment: between line 2 and line 3

Comment: hi may I know what is the error?